# If there a way to get yahoo data using python pandas reader without running into this error {}

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

```
import pandas as pd

import datetime as dt

import pandas_datareader.data as web

from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
```

## Pulling Data

```
start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

stocks = web.DataReader(['FB','AMZN', 'AAPL', 'NFLX', 'GOOGL', 'MSFT'], 
                        'yahoo', start, end)

stocks_close = pd.DataFrame(web.DataReader(['FB','AMZN', 'AAPL', 'NFLX', 'GOOGL', 'MSFT'], 
                                           'yahoo', start, end)['Close'])
```

## Here's the error i get , i understand there's an option of importing yfinance and using the override function but i can not seem to actually get this to work. Thank you in advance.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Niquel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 272
    warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)
SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'FB', replacing with NaN.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Niquel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 272
    warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)
SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'AMZN', replacing with NaN.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Niquel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 272
    warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)
SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'AAPL', replacing with NaN.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Niquel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 272
    warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)
SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'NFLX', replacing with NaN.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Niquel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 272
    warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)
SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'GOOGL', replacing with NaN.
```

Comment: I have run your code in my environment and have not encountered any errors. My environment is as follows. `pandas_datareader:0.10.0 pandas:1.4.0` Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Thanks a million times. I installed <pandas_datareader:0.10.0> and it works.